# Splitting Pandas dataframe by columns and concatenate to create single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file in the following format:

[image]

I want to read it using Python and concatenate the tables(the number of tables could change) into a single one, and add a column with the road name next to each table

So it would look like:

[image]

I read in the excel file

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(input_fp, dtype='str').dropna(how='all')

And the dataframe looks like:

[image]

I'm thinking that splitting the dataframe by columns with all nan values, or columns with a header should work. But unsure how to do this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Test data:

```
{'Unnamed: 0': {0: 'Start Time', 1: '06:01:00', 2: '06:31:00', 3: '07:31:00', 4: '08:31:00'}, 'Unnamed: 1': {0: 'End Time', 1: '06:30:00', 2: '07:30:00', 3: '08:30:00', 4: '09:30:00'}, 'Unnamed: 2': {0: 'Number of Cars', 1: '5343', 2: '2545', 3: '2434', 4: '3424'}, 'Unnamed: 3': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 'Unnamed: 4': {0: 'Start Time', 1: '06:01:00', 2: '06:31:00', 3: '07:31:00', 4: '08:31:00'}, 'Unnamed: 5': {0: 'End Time', 1: '06:30:00', 2: '07:30:00', 3: '08:30:00', 4: '09:30:00'}, 'Unnamed: 6': {0: 'Number of Cars', 1: '5343', 2: '2545', 3: '2434', 4: '3424'}, 'Unnamed: 7': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}, 'Unnamed: 8': {0: 'Start Time', 1: '06:01:00', 2: '06:31:00', 3: '07:31:00', 4: '08:31:00'}, 'Unnamed: 9': {0: 'End Time', 1: '06:30:00', 2: '07:30:00', 3: '08:30:00', 4: '09:30:00'}, 'Unnamed: 10': {0: 'Number of Cars', 1: '5343', 2: '2545', 3: '2434', 4: '3424'}}
```

Comment: [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) read linked post & provide your `df.head().to_dict()` by text.

Comment: And first, use the following code to specify the header when creating df.  `df = pd.read_excel(input_fp, header=1, dtype='str').dropna(how='all')` Then, if you provide `df.head().to_dict()` by text, we will tell you how to reshape.

Comment: @z star I say it again, make df by following code `df = pd.read_excel(input_fp, header=1, dtype='str').dropna(how='all')` header=1 is important. plz make header & provide `df.head().to_dict()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you don't use `header=1` as @PandaKim mentioned in the comments, you first need to move 1st row to the header like this:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.drop(0,axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Then one way of getting your output would be to loop through the columns and split where the column is nan, and then concat all the splits:

```
# use this to split
cols_nans = [i for i,x in enumerate(df.columns) if not isinstance(x, str)]
cols_nans.append(len(df.columns))

# init
dfs = []
i = 0
for idx, j in enumerate(cols_nans ):
  df_sub = df.iloc[:, i:j] # split
  df_sub['Road'] = 'Road' + chr(idx+65) # only will work if #roads <26
  i = j+1
  dfs.append(df_sub)
print(pd.concat(dfs))
```

Output:

```
0 Start Time  End Time Number of Cars   Road
1   06:01:00  06:30:00           5343  RoadA
2   06:31:00  07:30:00           2545  RoadA
3   07:31:00  08:30:00           2434  RoadA
4   08:31:00  09:30:00           3424  RoadA
1   06:01:00  06:30:00           5343  RoadB
2   06:31:00  07:30:00           2545  RoadB
3   07:31:00  08:30:00           2434  RoadB
4   08:31:00  09:30:00           3424  RoadB
1   06:01:00  06:30:00           5343  RoadC
2   06:31:00  07:30:00           2545  RoadC
3   07:31:00  08:30:00           2434  RoadC
4   08:31:00  09:30:00           3424  RoadC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `header` as parameter of `read_excel`:

```
df = (pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=[0, 2])
        .dropna(how='all', axis=1).rename_axis(columns=['Road', None])
        .stack('Road').reset_index('Road').reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     Road Start Time  End Time  Number of Cars
0  Road A   06:01:00  06:30:00            5343
1  Road B   06:01:00  06:30:00            5343
2  Road C   06:01:00  06:30:00            5343
```